# How to check if an array has the same elements as another one in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to match all documents where field `arr`, which is an array of object Ids, has same elements of a given one no matther the position.

I tried:

```
[
  {
    $match:{
      arr: givenArr
    }
  }
]
```

or

```
[
  {
    $match:{
      arr: {
          $in: givenArr
        }
    }
  }
]
```

The first pipeline matches all the documents that have same elements in the `same position`.

The second pipeline matches all the documents that has at least one element in the given array.

For example if I have a couple of documents like:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de4"),
    arr: [
      ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de1"),
      ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de2"),
      ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de3"),
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de5"),
    arr: [
      ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de7"),
      ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de8"),
      ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de9"),
    ]
  },
]
```

If I need to match all of those documents that have `arr` same as

```
[
  ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de8"),
  ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de9"),
  ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de7"),
]
```

I want to get only the second document.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could treat each array as a set and use `"$setEquals"`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $setEquals: [
      "$arr",
      [
        ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de8"),
        ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de9"),
        ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de7")
      ]
    ]
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SHc1audjE8f).

Comment: For those who needs `$setEquals` works also in `$project` pipeline with aggregation framework. GG @rickhg12hs

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the sorted results of your 2 arrays computed by `$sortArray`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$arr",
          sortBy: 1
        }
      },
      {
        $sortArray: {
          input: [
            ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de8"),
            ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de9"),
            ObjectId("639a0e4cc0f6595d90a84de7"),
            
          ],
          sortBy: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fomkXmVCA6g)